# Background made with procedural shapes

Tags: unity, procedural-generation, geometry, graphic-effects

I would like to know how to make a background like Super Hexagon managed to do: a hexagon in the middle and equally sized trapezoids.

There's a screenshot below & the [here is the effect in motion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2sz0mI_6tLQ).

How can this be done? Can I use a big sprite or procedural meshes?

[image: Super Hexagon]

Comment: You should include an image, because this is a game I've never heard of. Also, "How did they do it?" is not something we can necessarily answer. Asking "how do I do it?" is.

Comment: I can't upload directly so I added a link

Comment: I didn't say how did they do it. I asked how can it be done

Comment: I assume you don't want to clone Super Hexagon's look precisely, but rather you want techniques to do something analogous in your game. Can you tell us a bit more about how you want your game to look/behave?

Comment: I would personally use Image Masks, to mask out parts of the image into each triangle

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve the look is to use a shader that draws the stripes in each trapezoid. I would do it by defining the distance between 2 stripes and the width of brighter stripe. Then I would tile the plane that the trapezoid is in. Something like this (pseudo-glsl) :

```
uniform float bandWidth; // The width between 2 bright stripes
uniform float stripeWidth; // The width of 1 bright stripe
uniform vec4 bandColor;
uniform vec4 stripeColor;
void main()
{
    vec4 color = bandColor;
    vec2 texCoord = gl_TexCoord[0];
    texCoord.x = mod(texCoord.x, bandWidth);
    if (texCoord.x < stripeWidth)
    {
        color = stripeColor;
    }
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

This draws the pattern left to right in 1 trapezoid. If you rotate and repeat the trapezoid, it should make the pattern all the way around the hexagon.

You could use different values for the `bandWidth` and `stripeWidth` in different trapezoids to get some of the different patterns in the linked video. It also looks like the trapezoids alternate the `bandColor` to be slightly darker or lighter.

Comment: So you are saying make a plane and add this shader to it?

Comment: Not exactly. I'm saying make a trapezoid and add something like this shader to it. Then position the trapezoids around the center so they make the shape you want.

Comment: So to sum it up, make a trapezoid using the Mesh class. Then add this shader to it which will create the stripes. After that position the trapezoids around the center?

Comment: I think so. I've not used Unity before, so not sure how the Mesh class works. But that's the general idea.